# Python3 Singleton metaclass method not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, singleton, metaclass

I saw a lot of methods of making a singleton in Python and I tried to use the metaclass implementation with Python 3.2 (Windows), but it doesn"t seem to return the same instance of my singleton class.

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()
print(a is b) # False
```

I use the decorator implementation now which is working, but I'm wondering what is wrong with this implementation?

Comment: I know this thread is old, but why were you using Python2 syntax if you were programming in Python3?

Comment: Is anyone else bothered that the class is allowed to take arguments? What behavior is defined when a singleton is "instantiated" with two different sets of arguments?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The metaclass syntax [has changed](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) in Python3. See [the documentaition](http://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation).

```
class MyClass(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass
```

And it works:

```
>>> MyClass() is MyClass()
True
```

Comment: Your name is very appropriate. All the tutorials I found are very nice but were never updated for Python 3. You just truncated to a couple of hours what might have taken days... Thanks.

Comment: You left the parent class (object) out. Is it still valid and is there a reason to use something like `class MyClass(object, metaclass=Singleton)`?

Comment: Iff you want to subclass something other than `object`. With `object` it's redundant.

Comment: I have to do `class MyClass (__metaclass__=Singleton):`, that is double underscores on either side of metaclass or else I get `The word metaclass is not correctly spelled`.