# How to add a dictionary attribute to python class object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nlp

I have a bit of code I'm working with ([specifically Parsetron](https://github.com/Kitt-AI/parsetron)) which was written for Python 2.7 which I'm trying to run using python 3.4 and unsurprisingly it's throwing errors.

The error I'm specifically looking at is this:

```
def __new__(cls):
    return cls.__dict__['_grammar_']

KeyError: '_grammar_'
```

`cls` is class object, which indeed does not have the key "`_grammar_`". My question is of course, how to get rid of this error and why it appears. In python 2.7, does `__dict__` add a key value to the class object whereas Python 3.x doesn't? Running through the thread during debugging it doesn't seem to add this value anywhere. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] for this, rather than two disembodied lines, and give the full traceback?

Comment: it looks like the __new__ method is trying to implement some sort of singleton - however, if that really is the total of the __new__ method it's not doing it very well. As @jonrsharpe says - a proper example is needed for this:

Comment: See [method 3 for creating a singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6760685/3001761), and a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17237857/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, you can see that the `Grammar._grammar_` class attribute is actually [set by the metaclass](https://github.com/Kitt-AI/parsetron/blob/master/parsetron/parsetron.py#L87):

```
dct["_grammar_"] = GrammarImpl(name, dct)
```

However, `Grammar` [uses the 2.x syntax](https://github.com/Kitt-AI/parsetron/blob/master/parsetron/parsetron.py#L114) for setting a metaclass:

```
__metaclass__ = MetaGrammar
```

To adapt this for Python 3.x, use the [new syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax):

```
class Grammar(metaclass=MetaGrammar):
```